# Rails: Limiting how many tasks a user can claim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm writing a simple project management app as a learning exercise in Rails.

I have a `task` model, and a `user` model. The `task` model has a `user` field denoting which user has claimed a given task.

There are a couple of things I want to enforce in the model level but am not sure how:

1. Each user may claim up to five tasks, and no more.
2. Each user may only claim tasks for their own (i.e, the `user` field can be set to the currently active user, and not to any other user). In other words, you can't assign tasks - users may only claim them.

Is trying to enforce these as validations the right thing to do? Could you point me in the direction of the validations I need? Should I write my own?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your own validations. There is no default for the ones you are looking for. Here is some sample code:

```
validate :has_only_five_tasks

def has_only_five_tasks
  if User.find(self.user_id).tasks.count >= 5
    errors.add(:user_id, "User may only have 5 tasks assigned.")
  end
end
```

The other one is like the above, only the if changes, so i believe you can look into this and adapt to your own needs.